# Setup Weylus using USB tethering

Tags: usb, ip, usb-modem

Being behind corporate firewall, I need to make [Weylus](https://github.com/H-M-H/Weylus) works via USB Tethering.

The README says it's possible but doe not provide step-by-step instruction.

How can I have it working via USB Tethering? I don't know where to start.

I'm on Ubuntu 20.10, Linux 5.8

Answer (score 2):

Note: The other answer involves using `adb`, but actually there is no need to use `adb` at all or any other tools. This is with Android 12.

Here are the steps:

1. Connect your tablet to your PC via the USB cable.
2. On your tablet USB settings select "USB Tethering" (as opposed to "USB for file transfer")
3. On your linux machine, use `ifconfig` to find the ip address for your PC on the USB tether network, it should look something like this (in this case the ip address is `192.168.246.113`):

```
usb0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.246.113  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.246.255
```

4. Start Weylus
5. On your tablet connect to the ip address from above and port `1701`, for example `192.168.246.113:1701`

Pro-tip: if your tablet is connected via `usb0`, you can get Weylus to automatically display the QR code for the correct ip address with `weylus --bind-address $(ifconfig usb0 | grep -oP 'inet \K[^ ]+')`.

Answer (score 1):

Did it.

Here are the steps for future readers:

1. Connect your tablet to your PC via the USB cable
2. On your Android tablet, use "USB for file transfer" mode
3. Enable USB debugging on your tablet (see [here](https://www.kingoapp.com/root-tutorials/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-mode-on-android.htm) for instructions)
4. Install `adb` on your system (on Ubuntu, run `sudo apt-get install adb`)
5. Reverse the port you are going to use, so that your tablet will connect to your PC. The first port is the webserver, the second port is the websocket:

```
adb reverse tcp:1701 tcp:1701
adb reverse tcp:9001 tcp:9001
```

6. Run Wyelus and start the server
7. On your tablet, connect to `localhost:1701`. Use `localhost` and not an IP address.

Comment: I think the answer that I added below might suit most users better because it doesn't involve adb. You may want to consider marking it as the answer.